# Inner join with 3 tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, inner-join

table description:

- table a: id
- table b: id, c_id
- table c: id

a.id and b.id is the same data.

When I select on each, it works.

```sql
-- Both work.

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    a
INNER JOIN
    b ON a.id = b.id
;

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    b
INNER JOIN
    c ON c.id = b.c_id
;
```

But when I do this, it doesn't work. (returns 0 data)

```sql
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    a
INNER JOIN
    b ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN
    c ON c.id = b.c_id
;
```

What's the problem?

Comment: It's working as expected. Please check here https://dbfiddle.uk/LKCcKvne @user15348043

Comment: I thought it would be too, but I don't know why it's not working for my tables.

Comment: did you make it as I made it? Are my table structure and values correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.. I just copied and joined the two queries. But no data comes out.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the same as you described above. The result is as expected. Please check.

```
CREATE TABLE tempA(
id INT
);
INSERT INTO tempA(id) VALUES
(1),
(2);
CREATE TABLE tempB(
id INT,
c_id INT
);

INSERT INTO tempB(id,c_id) VALUES
(1,1),
(2,2);

CREATE TABLE tempC(
id INT
);

INSERT INTO tempC(id) VALUES
(1),
(2);

SELECT * FROM tempA;
SELECT * FROM tempB;
SELECT * FROM tempC;

SELECT 
    *
FROM
    tempA a
INNER JOIN
    tempB b ON a.id = b.id
INNER JOIN
    tempC c ON c.id = b.c_id;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempA;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempB;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tempC;
```

[image]